# How to simulate random encounters in python

Tags: python

I have some random outcomes, and I want to simulate the random outcomes.

```
outcomes_mapping = {0.10:"Outcome A", 0.60:"Outcome B", 0.30:"Outcome C"}
```

Outcome A should happen 10% of the time, outcome B 60% of the time, outcome C 30% of the time.

Currently, my solution is something like this:

```
def random_encounter():
    roll = np.random.rand()        
    if roll <= 0.1:
         return "Outcome A"
    if roll > 0.1 and roll <=0.6:
         return "Outcome B"
```

Is there some smarter way to do this? My solution obviously involves a lot of hard coding. Should I be using cumulative probabilities instead? Even if I did, my function would still be in a `if roll > 0.1, return this, else return that` format. If possible, I would like to maintain a master "outcomes mapping" dictionary which I can reference in my function.

Comment: I am trying to find a better way to write my function to "fish" out random encounters, as it currently involves a lot of hard coding.

Comment: @rahultyagi No it doesnt.

Comment: You can merge them in one line with list comprehension, if you change the outcomes_mapping slightly abit.

Comment: @rahultyagi Can you elaborate what are the levels this code is wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why would it not? `np.random.rand` returns random samples from a uniform distribution over ``[0, 1)``. Can you help me understand your thinking? Thanks.

Comment: Don't really understand what you're trying to say. But thanks for the good effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `weights` parameter in `random.choices`:

```
from collections import Counter
import random

outcomes_mapping = {0.10:"Outcome A", 0.60:"Outcome B", 0.30:"Outcome C"}

c = Counter()
for i in range(1000):
    c.update( random.choices([*outcomes_mapping.values()], weights=outcomes_mapping.keys()) )

print(c)
```

Prints:

```
Counter({'Outcome B': 596, 'Outcome C': 317, 'Outcome A': 87})
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution. I forgot to indicate that i am on Python 2.7, which doesn't have `random.choices`

Comment: @JamesSoh In Python 2.7 you can create a list that is representing your disambiguation of choices, e.g. `X = ['A'] + 6*['B'] + 3*['C']`, and then call `random.choice(X)`

Comment: @JamesSoh ... or you can use `numpy`-package. There is the method `numpy.random.choice`, which provides the argument `p`, that has the same influence on the output as `weights` for `random.choices` in Python 3.x.

Answer (score 0):

since you already have a dictionary with the values, you could do something like

```
cumulative = 0
for k in outcomes_mapping: 
    cumulative += k
    if roll <= cumulative:
        return outcomes_mapping[k]
```

That way, you only have to update the dictionary when changing or adding values.

The reason you need to keep the `cumulative` count is that your map contains absolute probabilities: Outcome B will show up 60% of the time, but that is rolled range "`0.1` to `0.7`", so we need to add the 10% from outcome A (thank you for pointing this out @marcus.aurelianus).

Comment: Guess your code will not fullfill 'Outcome A should happen 10% of the time, outcome B 60% of the time, outcome C 30% of the time'.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this, when mapping of outcomes looks like this, where keys hold lower and upper limit for each possibility:

`mapping = {(0.0, 0.1) : "A", (0.1, 1) : "B"}`

```
def roll(mapping, roll):
    for limit, val in mapping.items():
        if limit[0] < roll <= limit[1]:
            return val
```

Output:

```
roll(mapping, 0.1)
'A'

roll(mapping, 0.2)
'B'
```

Depending on what range do you want, and what input value for roll would be, you could use either slightly changed mapping (`0.0` to `-0.1` for example) or other check for ranges.